# Download original image from 500px using REST API

Tags: rest, 500px

I'm using the [500px REST API](https://github.com/500px/api-documentation) in order to retrieve information on photos, and download them.

Using the `photos/:id` [method](https://github.com/500px/api-documentation/blob/master/endpoints/photo/GET_photos_id.md) I'm retrieving the details of the photo.

The endpoint supports downloading the images in various sizes, via the `image_size` parameter (described [here](https://github.com/500px/api-documentation/blob/master/basics/formats_and_terms.md#image-urls-and-image-sizes)), however the largest image I can get is "2048px on the longest edge" (using the `2048` value).

Is there a way to download the original photo?

**Note:** I'm allowing users to download only their own photos, not photos of other users...

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's any way to get original image because if it was possible, developers would have built a web/mobile tool to download full-size images and no one would care about 500px Prime and buy images from 500px.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but your justification is wrong. The question is about downloading your *own* photos, not arbitrary third party photos. In either case, there is no way of downloading the original photo.